# Customizing Example Django App - Django Dev Pattern

Tags: python, django

I followed all 42 tutorials on the Try Django Youtube channel, and I'm trying to customize that project to make my own custom app.

My web app only needs two pages for now. One for users (which I only create in the admin) to log in, and another page to use the app. I'm trying to get the hang of the Django dev steps. Correct me if I'm wrong, so if I want to make a single page in a Django web app, I need to set it up in my `urls.py`, `views.py`, and make a template html file for it, right?

If I'm getting this order wrong or leaving anything out, any help or advice is appreciated. Can this pattern be found on Django documentation website, too?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? Experiment!

Comment: If you followed a 42 parts tutorial I'm sure you know this basics. Now try to do your model and when you'll be stuck come here again, it will be a pleasure to help you. Btw https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/ is the best django tutorial and you also have link to the official doc.

Comment: @Bestasttung: Seems like this tutorial is different from the youtube one. I'm going to complete that one to so I can solidify my skills and let me get the hang of it easier. Thanks for that recommendation! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django based on MTV (model, view, template) pattern. More about it here http://aijogja.pythonblogs.com/251_aijogja/archive/1433_django_tutorial-create_a_blog-part_6__mvt_model_view_template_section_1-homepage.html

For adding another page, setup route in urls.py (write regexp), add function in views.py (must return httpresponse) and create template.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to reference it again too in one of his tutorial videos. Thanks for the documentation link too! :)